# Ruby variable scope blocks

Tags: ruby

In C you can use statement blocks to isolate local variables from its parent scope.

```
int foo() {
    {
        int a;
    }
    // Here `a` is no longer in the scope.
}
```

But in Ruby the following fails to parse.

```
def foo
    do
        a = 1
    end
    puts a
end
```

Is there a trick to isolate variables into a scope in Ruby?

Comment: The notation for declaring an inline block is `begin ... end`, not `do ... end`.

Comment: In Ruby _scope_ gates are created by 3 keywords.. `def`, `class` and `module`.

Comment: https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/ruby/doc_bundle/Newcomers/ruby.html#blocks

Comment: @tadman `begin; a = 1; end; puts a` prints 1, so `a` is not confined to the scope of the begin block.

Answer (score 3):

The most appropriate "inner scope" in most cases is a separate method. Usually, if some of the data during a certain block of algorithm should not be visible outside, it's worth extracting this block into a separate method. And it could as well be, that this block could make a nice argument.

[As the docs state](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/localvars.html), these are all the cases that have their own local variable scope:

- `proc{ ... }` (and, consequently, blocks in method calls)
- `loop{ ... }` (a method that accepts a block, same as above)
- `def ... end` (a method implementation)
- `class ... end`
- `module ... end`
- the entire program (this is of no use in scope of the question though)

Answer (score 2):

The following works, but I suspect there are other ways.

```
proc {
    a = 5
}.call
```